# Hudson gitorious plugin?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, gitorious

Has anyone integrated a local copy of gitorious with Hudson?

Specifically, linking the sha1 on Hudson web page back to the gitorious web page.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) has gitorious linking support since version 1.1.11 (released July 22, 2011).

Configure it in the project/job settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work in the same fashion as hooking into a standard Git repository.

Comment: Thanks, the normal git plugin hooks me up to the repository.  I am looking for something that would link the sha1 to a gitorious web.